# Writing an iterator

Tags: iterator, rust

> Editor's note: This code example is from a version of Rust prior to 1.0 and is not valid Rust 1.0 code. Updated versions of this code no longer produce an error due to changes how `for` loops are implemented.

I'm writing a Vector struct in Rust.

```
pub struct Vector {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub z: f32,

    curr: uint
}
```

And I'd like to write a simple iterator for it, so that I can iterate over the elements of the vector. It's occasionally useful, plus I know next to nothing about iterators in Rust.

Here's what I've got at the moment.

```
impl Iterator<f32> for Vector {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<f32> {
        let new_next : Option<f32> = match self.curr {
            0 => Some(self.x),
            1 => Some(self.y),
            2 => Some(self.z), 
            _ => None
        };
        let new_curr = (self.curr + 1) % 4;
        mem::replace(&mut self.curr, new_curr);
        new_next
    }
}
```

Now ideally I'd like to be able to use this like:

```
let u = Vector::new(0.0f32, 0.0f32, 0.0f32);
for element in u {
    ///
}
```

However, I get the following compiler error:

```
 error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `u` as mutable
```

So I'm stumped. After a couple hours of Googling, I couldn't come up with anything. I feel like I'm missing something huge.

Comment: Please update this question or mark it in the title as being outdated; iterators now use associated types and this question no longer reflects the correct way to implement them in either the question or answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sure you really want the `Vector` *itself* to be an iterator? Usually structures and iterators into them are separate. Consider something like this:

```
pub struct Vector {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub z: f32,
}

pub struct VectorIter<'a> {
    vector: &'a Vector,
    cur: usize,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for VectorIter<'a> {
    type Item = f32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<f32> {
        let r = match self.cur {
            0 => self.vector.x,
            1 => self.vector.y,
            2 => self.vector.z,
            _ => return None,
        };
        self.cur += 1;
        Some(r)
    }
}

impl Vector {
    fn iter(&self) -> VectorIter {
        VectorIter {
            vector: self,
            cur: 0,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Vector { x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0 };
    for c in v.iter() {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

Because `Vector` is very simple, it can derive `Copy`, and its iterator can take it by value:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Vector {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub z: f32,
}

pub struct VectorIter {
    vector: Vector,
    cur: usize,
}

impl Iterator for VectorIter {
    type Item = f32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<f32> {
        let r = match self.cur {
            0 => self.vector.x,
            1 => self.vector.y,
            2 => self.vector.z,
            _ => return None,
        };
        self.cur += 1;
        Some(r)
    }
}

impl Vector {
    fn iter(&self) -> VectorIter {
        VectorIter {
            vector: *self,
            cur: 0,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = Vector { x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 3.0 };
    for c in v.iter() {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

This variant is probably better unless your `Vector` contains something other than coordinates. This variant is more flexible because it does not tie the iterator with the iterable, but on the other hand, exactly because of the same reason it may be undesirable (with `Copy` you can change the original value, and the iterator won't reflect it; without `Copy` and with references you won't be able to change the original value at all). The semantics you would want to use heavily depends on your use cases.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think when you implement iterator you have to assign type alias `type Item = f32;`. I couldn't compile this code as is on 1.7.0.

Answer (score 4):

> Editor's note: This answer is no longer useful as of Rust 1.0 due to changes how the `for` loop works.

Vladimir Matveev's answer is correct and explains what you should do. I'd like to add on by explaining your error a bit more.

> error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `u` as mutable

When you are iterating over something, you need to mutate *something* that tracks where you are. In your code, that's done by:

```
mem::replace(&mut self.curr, new_curr);
```

And Rust knows which thing you want to mutate because the method signature for `next` indicates it:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<f32>
```

The problem is that your object *is not mutable*:

```
let u = Vector::new(0.0f32, 0.0f32, 0.0f32);
```

If you change your code to

```
let mut u = Vector::new(0.0f32, 0.0f32, 0.0f32);
```

I'd expect your code to work as-is. All that being said, a separate iterator is probably the right way to go. However, you'll know more than we do about your code!