# How to properly implement Iterable structure in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

I'm trying to implement a structure that can be infinitely iterated. Think it like a natural number. I have a limitation: it can't implement `Copy` trait because the structure contains a `String` field.

I've also implemented an `Iterable` trait and its only member `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>`.

Currently, I have the following code to iterate over the first 10 items of my structure:

```
let mut counter = 0;
let mut game:Option<Game> = Game::new(&param);
loop {
    println!("{:?}", game); 

    game = g.next();
    counter = counter + 1;
    if counter > 10 { break; }
}
```

I'd like to give to users of my `crate` the ability to iterate over my struct using `for in` construction, like this:

```
for next_game in game {
  println!("{:?}", next_game);
}
```

Is it possible at all? How can I achieve this? How to make my code better and what I have to do with my struct?

Iterator implementation:

```
pub struct Game {
    /// The game hash
    pub hash: Vec<u8>
}

impl Iterator for Game {
    type Item = Game;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
        hasher.input(&hex::encode(&self.hash)); // we need to convert the hash into string first
        let result = hasher.result().to_vec();

        Some(Game {
            hash: result
        })
    }
}
```

Example: broken behavior with `for`

```
let mut game:Game = Game::new(&s).unwrap();
for g in game.take(2) {
    println!("{}", g);
}
```

Now if we run example, we will get two `Game` structs with same `hash`, while expected behavior is that the first `g` will have `hash` equal to SHA256(game.hash) and the next `g`'s hash will be SHA256(SHA256(game.hash)). It works properly when I call `.next()`.

Comment: What most people do is create a new struct, say `GameIter`, and provide it to the user like `game.iter()`.
Any struct that implements `Iterator` can be used in a `for ... in ...` expression and if you want to limit the number of iterations, simply use `take`.

Comment: This question would be significantly clearer if you provided an implementation of the `Game` struct.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin: And of the `next` function...

Comment: What is wrong with implementing `Iterator` and `IntoIter`?

Comment: Related: [Writing an Iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601115/writing-an-iterator?noredirect=1&lq=1), [How to implement Iterator and IntoIterator for a simple struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218886/how-to-implement-iterator-and-intoiterator-for-a-simple-struct/30220832) the answer is essentially in the question titles...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I've just updated a question with the implementation of Iterator and better explanation of the problem I address in my question.

Comment: All the question appeared because of a frustration that my implementation of Iterator works differently for `loop` and for `for`. The way my example with `loop` above works looks very same as described behavior of `for`, while I don't get expected behavior and can't catch what the problem with it, that's why I supposed that the problem is how I implement Iterator trait.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Rust iterators actually can be divided into 2 categories. Iterators which own the struct, thus can be created using `.into_iter()` which consumes `self`.

And iterators that iterate over structure without consuming it. They can be created be usually created using: `.iter`, `.iter_mut()`

For more information see related question: [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter)
And documention: [The three forms of iteration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/#the-three-forms-of-iteration)

To create iterator you should implement either `IntoIterator` trait, which will transform your structure into iterator or write functions which will create iterator: `iter_mut`, `iter`

`pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> IterMut<T>`

`pub fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T>`

So by convention you need 2 new types `IterMut` and `Iter`

```
impl Iterator for Iter {
    type Item = /* ... */;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        /* ... */
    }
}

impl Iterator for IterMut {
    type Item = &mut /* ... */;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

They usually contain in them reference to the parent structure. For example for linked list it can be current node (which is updated every iteration). For array-like structures it can be index and reference to the parent, so index will incremented every time and element accessed using index operator and etc..