# Specifying lifetime of the associated type in the Iterator trait

Tags: rust

I'm a Rust newbie and I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do the following in Rust is:

```
struct ThingIterator {
    current: String,
    stop: String,
}

impl Iterator for ThingIterator {
    type Item = &str;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&str> {
        if self.current == self.stop {
            return None;
        }
        // For testing
        self.current = self.stop;
        Some(&self.current)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pi = ThingIterator {
        current: String::from("Ask"),
        stop: String::from("Zoo"),
    };
    println!("Number of things={}", pi.count());
}
```

My error is:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:7:17
  |
7 |     type Item = &str;
  |                 ^ expected lifetime parameter

error: aborting due to previous error
```

This makes sense, I need to specify how long the reference returned from next() is going to be valid. I'm guessing for the function itself it's fine as the lifetime is elissed (not sure about the conjugation of elission) - but I somehow need to define the lifetime of the "type Item = &str" row.

In my case it will be valid as long as "current" is valid, i.e. the same lifetime as "self".

I haven't seen anything in the Rust book or other documentation that helps me figure out this case.

P.S. Sorry if I'm butchering the nomenclature, I'm very much new to Rust.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lifetime on `&mut self` in `next` isn't in scope when defining the type `Item`, so `Item` can't depend on that lifetime. Instead, it's typical to have `ThingIterator` hold references instead of owned data. If there's still a structure that has owned data, you'll probably implement `IntoIterator` for `&OwnsData` to convert into the type that uses references.

```
// ThingIterator is now generic in the lifetime 'a
// and it holds references rather than owned Strings.
struct ThingIterator<'a> {
    current: &'a str,
    stop: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for ThingIterator<'a> {
    // Now we can use the lifetime from ThingIterator here.
    type Item = &'a str;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        if self.current == self.stop {
            return None;
        }
        // For testing
        self.current = self.stop;
        Some(self.current)
    }
}

// Typically, you'll have a type that owns its data
// Like Vec<T>, HashSet<T>, etc.
struct OwnsData {
    current: String,
    stop: String,
}

impl OwnsData {
    // We'll have the traditional method that takes a reference
    // to self and returns an iterator over references into self.

    // Explicit lifetimes aren't needed, but it might help with understanding.
    // fn iter<'a>(&'a self) -> ThingIterator<'a> {

    fn iter(&self) -> ThingIterator {
        ThingIterator {
            current: &self.current,
            stop: &self.stop,
        }
    }
}

// Then, we'll implement IntoIterator for references to OwnsData
// using the OwnsData::iter method defined above.
// This is helpful because for loops and many iterator methods
// use IntoIterator to work.
impl<'a> IntoIterator for &'a OwnsData {
    // We'll be converting into ThingIterator
    type IntoIter = ThingIterator<'a>;
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn into_iter(self) -> ThingIterator<'a> {
        self.iter()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pi = ThingIterator {
        current: "Ask",
        stop: "Zoo",
    };
    println!("Number of things={}", pi.count());

    // Alternatively, we could start with Strings
    // and use OwnsData
    let tau = OwnsData {
        current: "Ask".to_string(),
        stop: "Zoo".to_string(),
    };
    println!("Number of things={}", tau.iter().count());
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=39aee58beba4182ab4791da80a18cb0c)

See also

- [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter)
- [How to properly implement Iterable structure in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379841/how-to-properly-implement-iterable-structure-in-rust)
- [How to implement Iterator and IntoIterator for a simple struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218886/how-to-implement-iterator-and-intoiterator-for-a-simple-struct)

P.S. the word you're looking for is "elided".

Answer (score 3):

You can't, yet. This would require [generic associated types (GATs)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md). As of today, it is still just a RFC.

The current `Iterator` /  `Stream` API is sometimes called "detached":

> The idea is that `Item` that gets returned by `Stream` is “detached” from `self`, which means that it can be stored and moved about independently from `self`.

Hypothetically, after GAT is landed, one would be able to write something like:

```rust
trait AttachedStream {
    type Item<'s> where Self: 's;
    //       note the `'s` here!

    fn poll_next<'s>(
        self: Pin<&'s mut Self>,
        cx: &mut Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Option<Self::Item<'s>>>;
    //                         ^^^^
    // `'s` is the lifetime of the `self` reference.
    // Thus, the `Item` that gets returned may
    // borrow from `self`.
}
```

That's exactly what you want. Check out [Niko's async interview #2](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2019/12/10/async-interview-2-cramertj-part-2/) for more interesting details.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting! I accepted the other answer as an answer as it has an example of how I could proceed today, but I loved your details about upcoming features. Thanks!